# Execute a script in R console

Tags: r, graph, output, profiling

I've a .R script which has various output including a graph (I use ggplot2) and various informations from the graph. However, I never executed a script in R and I only started learning it very recently. To do so, I've been downloading the [R console][1] (Mac User). From what I've seen on documentation, I simply need to call my file using source().

```
source(file="/Users/MyName/Desktop/DataScript/MyFile.R", local = TRUE)
```

What I'm doing in this file is a non-linear regression (using dplyr, nls, ...). 
After calling the file with source, the message on the console seems normal but I don't understand it:

Looking at the .CSV document, nothing new in there. I looked at ggsave as suggested but I don't see why it's useful here... Also tried to do a "RUN All" in R-Studio but doesn't seem to give the plots as well.

Should I maybe remove the comments lines ##. By the way, the code should be OK, it has been written by someone who already executed it.

Comment: can you publish the contents of that .R file here? that may be helpful to explain the last part of the output. The rest is just information about packages and usually uncritical. besides as a beginner I suggest RStudio it's free and more convenient than the console.

Comment: Look into `write.csv` to output data. Look into the packages `ggplot` to make plots and `ggsave` to save plots.

Comment: Edited my message with the code and different informations...Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there's a few things to cover here.

R doesn't output the results of an assignment to the console. So if you want to see your graph after you've created it and assigned it to `P1`, you will need to call `P1` on a line by itself. I.e. last two lines should be:

```
P1 <- P1 + geom_ribbon(data=Prediction,aes(ymin=lwr,ymax=upr),alpha=0.3,colour="red")
P1
```

Then, when you source your script, it should display the graph saved as P1.

If you want to *save* the plot to use elsewhere, that's where `ggsave` can come in handy.

If you want to save your data file or variables, that's when `write.csv` will be useful.

Now, the output from loading dplyr:

```
Attaching package: 'dplyr'

The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':

filter, lag

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Waiting for profiling to be done...
```

The last line is output by you, so it's to be expected. The other lines are just saying that `dplyr` contains functions with the same names as functions in `stats` and functions in `base`. You can basically ignore this, unless you really need to use the functions which are listed as masked, in which case you'll need to use for example:

```
 stats::filter
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Really helps. Could you just explain what do you mean by 'write.csv' ? For example if I want to get my variables "K", "B" and "nu" ? Maybe could be useful with an example :-)

Comment: Type `?write.csv` at the console and read the documentation, or just Google it. Here's one page I found by doing that: http://rprogramming.net/write-csv-in-r/. Basically, you will use `write.csv(variable, file = "path/to/file.csv")`.